# Select blog articles by tag

Tags: php, mysql

I have a custom working blog. Everything works fine I was just wondering if anyone knows of a better way to select articles containing tags from a mysql database.

Currently the tags are stored in the "blog" table, under "blog_tags" and the articles are retreaved using LIKE '%tag%'. I this worked fine until I had 2 tags containing the same word e.g. website and website design.

Using the above method by searching for tags like website I would get the results containing the website tag and website design.

To fix the solution I added "*" at the beginning and end of each tag so blog_tags now looks like *tag 1*, *tag 2*, *tag 3*, *And so on...

Now I just search for articles with blog_tags like '%*tag here*%'. This works perfectly but there is probably a better way. Any ideas?

The query currently used is:

```
"SELECT * FROM `blog` WHERE `active` = 'y' AND `blog_tags` LIKE '%*" . str_replace("-", " ", $tag) . "*%' ORDER BY `blog_created` DESC LIMIT " . $startfrom . "," . $limit
```

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have multivalued fields in a database. Given your example, it seems that you have blogs that have many tags and tags that correspond to many blogs. This is a many-to-many relationship.

As a rule of thumb, many-to-many relationships generate a new table. So the database schema you should be using would be something like:

```
Blogs(*Id*, activ, date_created)
Tags(*Id*, text)
Blog_Tag(*BlogId*, *TagId*)
```

Primary keys are displayed between asterisks.

So, if you want to search all blogs tagged with 'mysql' you would do something like:

```
select * from blogs b
join blog_tag bt on b.id = bt.blogid
join tags t on bt.tagid = t.id
where t.text = 'mysql'
```

Of course, if you know the TagId in advance, you won't need the join on Tags.

Hope this has cleared some doubts.

Answer (score 3):

You have a relational database. It is designed to store structured data. Don't invent your own structures and then store those in fields.

This is a standard [many to many relationship](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php).

Create a table "tags" and a association table with two columns which are both foreign keys (tag id and blog entry id).

Then use a JOIN to get the entries you care about.